# Exponential time of entrance to a store

Tags: probability, statistics, proof-verification, exponential-distribution

Suppose that the time between entrance of two consecutive customers to a store follows an exponential distribution of mean 2 minutes. A person is observing this store at a time and see there are no customers inside. what is the probability that  after 5 minutes, no customers enter the shop.

---

I think the answer is very easy. Because exponential distribution is memoryless We simply find $P(X\geq 5) = 1-P(X\leq5) = 1-( 1 - e^{- \frac{1}{2} 5}) = e^{-\frac{1}{2} 5}$

Is my reasoning correct? it seems the problem is very easy but I found this in an exam and it was marked as medium difficulty.

Comment: seems your reasoning is correct. Maybe the difficulty lays in realizing the ED is memoryless and that makes it medium difficult?

Comment: @Steven31415 Probably that is the reason this question is marked as medium.